# Gracenote GNSDK for ios: video lookup don't return season number

Tags: gracenote

I've setup the Gracenote SDK for iOs and successfully made some videos lookup.
I've noticed that for series the sdk correctly return the episode number but don't return season number and for many series.

Here are the logs (Big Bang Theory)

```
airing start:   2015-10-03T10:05
airing end:     2015-10-03T10:30
channel tui:      251537434
channel tag:      F65C41B31CA03052BAD934B93C9ACF57
channel name:     NRJ 12
channel callsign: NRJ 12
channel number:   
program tui:      556745075
program tag:      63D1515CDA5AD50A6579997F97598833
program title:    The Big Bang Theory
program subtitle: La démission de Penny
program seasonNumber: 0
program episode: 13
```

for:

```
NSLog(@"program tui:      %@", program.tui);
NSLog(@"program tag:      %@", program.tuiTag);
NSLog(@"program title:    %@", program.officialTitle.display);
NSLog(@"program subtitle: %@", program.subtitle.display);
NSLog(@"program seasonNumber: %lu", (unsigned long)program.seasonNumber);
NSLog(@"program episode: %lu", (unsigned long)program.seasonEpisodeNumber);
```

Did I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing it right. The season data does not exist for this series in your region. A workaround I can think of is do a follow up query using **OnConnect API** to get the season number.
Here is how: use the program subtitle you received as the query string, specify entityType as "episode" and descriptionLang to your language ("fr" in your case), and make a **Program Search** method call. Below is the query, FYI.
`http://data.tmsapi.com/v1.1/programs/search?q=La+d%C3%A9mission+de+Penny&entityType=episode&descriptionLang=fr&api_key=YOUR_ONCONNECT_API_KEY`
About OnConnect API, please visit http://developer.tmsapi.com for more details.

There may be another workaround using another Gracenote API. I will do some research and update this answer.